# Cortana App - Freeform Content?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, cortana

I'm developing a CortanaApp and for some user queries I would like to display an inline (i.e., inside the Cortana Canvas) chart or list of items (maybe links), etc. My question is, what can I use to display a content similar to the ones the default Cortana apps use?

For instance, suppose that for one user query I would like to return a weather forecast with some charts and tables, what can I use to display such content?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact back with the user through cortana itself then you need to write a [Voice Command Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185608.aspx) file.

This can be extensively customized. So check if this works as per your requirements.